# Angular js , calling function to get string array from data in angular FireStore

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and am trying to fetch details from Firebase as a string array using the following function:

Firestore : companies > details > app > name: "WM,TT,MP"

```
getCompanies(): string [] {
var appl: string []  = [] ;

this.db.database.ref("companies/details/app/").on('value', function (snap) {

  snap.val().name.split(",").forEach(function(x:string){
    appl.push(x);
    console.log(">>>first "+appl.length);
  });

  });

  console.log("Reached here ");
  console.log(">>>second "+appl.length);
  return appl;
}
```

When i am calling getCompanies from a component on init like

```
 ngOnInit() {

    console.log(">>>"+this.localservice.getCompanies().length);


  }
```

It is running without any error , but i am getting the below output and i am not getting the string [] . the length is coming blank .

```
Reached here 
>>>second 0
>>>0
>>>first 1
>>>first 2
>>>first 3
```

So the issue is , the second step is getting executed before first step . As a result  i am getting the string [] as blank , how to get this work in angular

Comment: It is simple because the method containing first 1 ,first 2, first 3 is a response from a web service . And the rest will be executed before getting response. If you want to have it in this order you should move function inside the response of the webservice.

Comment: i tried like this but still not working  : getCompanies(): string[] {
    var appl: string []  = [] ;
    this.db.database.ref("companies/details/app/").on('value', function (snap) {
    snap.val().name.split(",").forEach(x => appl.push(x))});
     return appl;
    }

Comment: return appl should be inside also

Comment: but i have defined appl outside the on function .. this line , getCompanies(): string[] {" .   >>>>>> "function should return value" ,

Answer (score 0):

You are logging and returning the appl outside callback function this is why second is getting log before the first.

Put logging and return for appl inside the callback function as below:

```js
getCompanies(): string [] {
var appl: string []  = [] ;

this.db.database.ref("companies/details/app/").on('value', function (snap) {

  snap.val().name.split(",").forEach(function(x:string){
    appl.push(x);
    console.log(">>>first "+appl.length);
  });
  
       console.log("Reached here ");
       console.log(">>>second "+appl.length);
       
 return appl;

 });
```